In the redesigned [Watched tags], the 'see all' link incorrectly(?) opens the edit window
The redesigned [Watched tags] doesn't show all my watched tags but it does have a 'see all' link. There is a gear icon which opens an edit window where tags can be added and removed from being watched. The 'see all' link opens the same edit window.
This seems like an issue.
Before the 'see all' link was added, I could click a tag to see questions that have the tag. In the edit window the tags can't be clicked. Because the 'see all' link opens the edit window, instead of just showing all tags, functionality is now missing - I can't use the [Watched tags] to select questions for any of my watched tags. I can only do that for the few (five in my case) tags that show.
Is this a bug? Is the 'see all' link incorrectly hooked to the edit window? Should 'see all' just be showing all tags?

Related: Cannot interact with tags that are overflowing the visible Watched Tags widget on the new frontpage

I can't believe that. It was totally fine before the redesign. Then it became almost unusable with the 2 and a half lines of links and the scroll. Still you could scroll and click each tag. Now there's no more scroll but a "See all" link and the entire list is now totally useless since no tag can be clicked. That redesign just makes me come less and less often. That's a fact.

@MrUpsidown SE have elected to use a losing strategy for their "redesign". They try to come up with a minimal viable product, then expand it with more features. But that works if you're adding something new. If you're trying to replace an existing thing, the "minimal" is way bigger and should probably encompass 90% of the functionality. We currently have maybe 60% for the tags.

See Updated Homepage Widgets feedback. It's not done yet. Agreed that it's not ideal to redesign like this, quite confusing to know what is broken and what simply isn't finished yet.

The intention is not to break anyone's workflow, but I think this particular use case for the homepage might've been overlooked. It was a conscious decision for "See all" to open the modal. The modal's tags will be links soon, so hopefully that helps. Alternatively, you can still see the Watched Tags widget how it was before on the Questions Page

IMHO professional sites don't change to a prototype layout with missing features. The change when they have a layout that is ready to go publc!

Agree. It cannot be right that the function of the dialog changes from filtering questions to suddenly editing tags when you expand it. REALLY POOR DESIGN.
